# How to show a tree structure database in Splunk?

Tags: mongodb, splunk, dbx, splunk-query, database

How to display a tree structure database table/collection(any database) in Splunk.
For example: If we have Parent that has ChildA and ChildB. Further ChildA has ChildA1, ChildA2 and ChildA3. ChildB has ChildB1 and ChildB2.
When I choose Parent, it should display all the connected children of it in Splunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Splunk can natively do this.. Perhaps look into the Premium ITSI app within Splunk?